# execute python funtion from within html with django

Tags: python, django

So, i have a website hosted on a raspberry pi running django. i have my home.html where i want to display a menu made of images. when the images are clicked i want them to run a python script/function. Can anyone help me with this at all??

On another note, i don't want the page to change. it's just one page with images that when clicked execute different code.

I have manage to get the code to run but it runs when the page loads as apposed to when the button is clicked.

Maybe django isn't the answer here?

Comment: Given that you have to run python code from a django `view` and that said view returns a http response resulting in a page reload, you have to make an ajax call to the view to trigger whatever code you want to run. That would leave your page unchanged...

Answer (score 2):

To execute server code on a client side action, you'll obviously have to make a request.

In your case probably an ajax request since you won't need to reload the page.

Below is a simple example of an ajax request :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/yourpath', true); //will trigger http://yourdomain.com/yourpath.
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { //200 means OK
    console.log(this.responseText); //in your browser : F12 => Console. This is what the server returned.
  }
};

xhr.send();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. i don't suppose you could explain how i would do this? what code would i need to put into the html? and where i could put my python code?

Comment: Do you use a javascript library like JQuery ?

Comment: Thanks for that sample code, i'll give it a go! Could you also give me an example image link that would use the above script to call the python code?